# Where is Xkb getting its configuration?

Tags: xorg, xkb, cinnamon

Is there a way to query where `xkb` is getting its configuration from?
Under ArchLinux I have `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf` with:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "system-keyboard"
    MatchIsKeyboard "on"
    Option "XkbLayout" "us,us"
    Option "XkbVariant" "altgr-intl,colemak"
    Option "XKbOptions" "ctrl:nocaps,grp:alt_shift_toggle"
EndSection
```

but when I start up, if I do `setxkbmap -query`, I only get

```
rules:      evdev
model:      evdev
layout:     us,us
variant:    altgr-intl,
```

So neither the alternative variants nor options are recognized (needless to say, I cannot change layout). If I however run

```
setxkbmap -layout "us,us" -variant "altgr-intl,colemak" -option "ctrl:nocaps,grp:alt_shift_toggle"
```

I get the correct

```
rules:      evdev
model:      evdev
layout:     us,us
variant:    altgr-intl,colemak
options:    ctrl:nocaps,grp:alt_shift_toggle
```

So is there a possibility something is overwriting my configuration?
I am running GNOME/Cinnamon

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, Gnome overrides the `xkb` `X` settings.
You can set `xkb` layout/options in Gnome either using  the CLI tools `gsettings`/`dconf` or via the GUI tool `dconf-editor`.
So, using `gsettings`, open a terminal and run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('xkb', 'us'), ('xkb', 'us+altgr-intl'), ('xkb', 'us+colemak')]"
```

and

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['ctrl:nocaps','grp:alt_shift_toggle']"
```

---

Or fire up `dconf-editor` and edit like this (note each value must be quoted and multiple values are delimited by `comma+space`):

[image]

and

[image]

Both methods should yield the same results.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. In dconf-editor, my current setting seems to be [('xkb', 'us+altgr-intl'), ('xkb', 'us+colemak')], so it should work, shouldn't it? Or do I need the first ('xkb','us')? There is also the possibility it is still messing something up. Can I stop GNOME from overriding the xkb settings?

Comment: It should work without the first `('xkb, 'us')`, at least it works on my install (it doesn't hurt to add it and see if it makes any difference). If it still doesn't work then something must be wrong on your side as I am also on Archlinux and setting your layouts and options works fine on my side. Also, I don't think you can stop Gnome from overriding the `xkb` settings as it's hardcoded into [gnome-settings-daemon](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2012-June/msg00160.html)

Comment: Mmmm didn't work either way, I still get the broken result. If I however change the order to [('xkb', 'us+colemak'), ('xkb', 'us+altgr-intl')], it does get the colemak configuration (and not the altgr one), but setxkbmap -query gives only `variant:    colemak, `. A bug, perhaps? I don't know whom I could report to.

Comment: Ok, I tried it again with dvorak instead of colemak and it worked. I put colemak again, and it did work this time....weird. Thansk a lot.