# Map right alt to left control

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xkb

I would like to have my <kbd>right alt</kbd> key work as <kbd>left control</kbd> while still having <kbd>left control</kbd> work as left control. So I edited my evdev file like this:

```
<LALT> = 64;
<LCTL> = 37; // original binding 37
<SPCE> = 65;
<RCTL> = 105;
<RALT> = 37; // original binding: 108
```

However this does not work, now neither key is working as <kbd>ctrl</kbd>. How can I make this work?

Comment: How exactly are you loading your "evdev" file? This looks a bit like a custom kernel keyboard translation table (which has nothing to do with evdev), but a very incomplete one. And if you use X, you should use `xmodmap` instead.

Comment: How do I load it? It is the normal evdev under `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/`. It s being loaded upon login. What I posted with just a snippet from the file.

Comment: You already have the built-in `xkb` option (`ctrl:ralt_rctrl`) to make `RALT` function like `RCTL`. Do you absolutely need it to work as `LCTL` ? If not,  use the built-in option. Otherwise it should be trivial to define a new option in the `ctrl` file (it's the same code, just change `Control_R` to `Control_L`)...

Comment: @don_crissti for ***"what the h--- is this rabbithole"*** values of *"trivial"*

Comment: @quixotic - it should be trivial for someone who knows where the builtin option is defined and who also knows how to define a custom option or for someone who doesn't know all those things but who is an inquisitive mind... ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The keycodes file you've changed is an XKB mapping that defines the symbol codes used in XKB layouts (`<FOO>`) by the keycodes emitted by the kernel keyboard driver when a key is pressed.  Changing the codes there doesn't change what code the key generates, it changes what code the XKB layout thinks its dealing with when it sees the altered symbol.

Assuming you can get your system XKB files back to their original state, the XKB way to do what you want is to load an option that will override the standard layout.  There's an existing option (`ctrl:ralt_rctrl`) that's close to what you want:

```
  # definition in /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev
  ctrl:rctrl_ralt       =       +ctrl(rctrl_ralt)
  # similar rule for swapped option?
  ctrl:ralt_rctrl       =       +ctrl(ralt_rctrl)
```

You can load that with `setxkbmap`:

```
$ setxkbmap -option ctrl:ralt_rctrl
```

If that does what you want, you can make it permanent by adding that command to a `.xprofile` or `.xinitrc` or your window manager's `autorun` script.  In GNOME you may need other steps.

If you still prefer to have <kbd>Alt_R</kbd> remapped as <kbd>Ctrl_L</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl_R</kbd>, you'd want to create a local override clause.  Use the existing option as a starting point; it's in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ctrl`.  See [my superuser answer on XKB modifications](https://superuser.com/a/1168603/685512) and some additional resources:

- http://madduck.net/docs/extending-xkb/
- http://apps.jcns.fz-juelich.de/doku/sc/xkbmap
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_Xorg
- [Where is Xkb getting its configuration?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66624/where-is-xkb-getting-its-configuration)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/451945/permanently-set-keyboard-layout-options-with-setxkbmap-in-gnome-unity

Comment: Why does **xmodmap -e "keycode 108 = Ctrl_R" ** does not work ?

Comment: @Talespin_Kit this answer is about the XKB system; you should [post a separate question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

The file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev` is not an "evdev file", it's one of the many source files for the X keyboard translation table (xkb). No, it's not loaded upon login. Instead it serves as a source file for the compiler `xkbcomp`, and the output of the compiled filed are loaded when the X server starts. The whole topic is a bit complex, so don't go about making changes randomly and expect stuff to work. Also, the usual way to make your own keyboard mapping is to write *new* files, and leave the old ones in place. See for example [An Unreliable Guide to XKB Configuration](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.600.7058) for an introduction.

If you want to make your right alt key work as control key, a better way is to leave those files as they are, make an `~/.Xmodmap` file with the following two lines

```
remove mod4 = Alt_R
add control = Alt_R
```

test that it works by looking at `xmodmap -pk` for the old state, then loading it with `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap`, then do again an `xmodmap -pk` and make sure it looks right.

The result of this will be that the <kbd>right alt</kbd> key still shows up under its own keycode, but is treated as the <kbd>control</kbd> modifier so you can use it in combination with other keys.

Some display managers load `~/.Xmodmap` by default on login, some of the new display managers have lost this feature and you'll have to configure them to do that.

Comment: `xmodmap` still works in many contexts. but it has been deprecated for a decade and won't be around in Wayland or other post-X11 contexts, so i advise avoiding it whenever possible.