# Linux mint bluetooth headphone connect resets keyboard map

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-layout, bluetooth

So I have a `~/.config/autostart/keyboard.desktop` file that tweaks my laptop keyboard layout on login. It does `setxkbmap -option "ctrl:nocaps"` amongst other things. This maps my caps lock key to ctrl. That part works fine. However, when I connect my bluetooth headset, somehow this setting is undone and my caps lock key goes back to being caps lock. I searched `/etc/udev` and there's only one script in there for a separate vendor that seems unrelated. How can I track down what's doing this, why, and how to avoid it?

Comment: I'm running KDE on Debian and having the same issue so it's not specific to Mint

Answer (score 0):

So it seems doing this via an autostart script that calls `setxkbmap` is not the right approach. I found [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/66657/25728) that explains how to set this in gnome via gsettings command line or dconf-editor or the main keyboard layout options GUI, and setting it that way seems to persist across USB/bluetooth disconnect/connects.